# power shell script starts photoshop, but photoshop scripts will not execute

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, photoshop-script

I have a powershell script that is invoced by task scheduler on windows server 2016. The powershell script starts a new process with photoshop. A script in photoshop will run that is supposed to create some images.

This is on a vm instance, and everything works fine if I have a remote desktop connected to the machine. But as soon as I disconnect from the machine, the script in photoshop will not run. Photoshop will open, but not do anything. If I connect to the machine again, and click on photoshop, it will run its scripts.

Is there anything I can do to make photoshop run as if I was connected with remote desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Task scheduler jobs don't run in an interactive session.

It's possible the scripts inside Photoshop only run when Photoshop is executed interactively.